# HTML5 audio IE9 error: Unexpected call to method or property access

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, audio

I have a problem with part of my javascript code in IE9.

When I start the page I get an error: **Unexpected call to method or property access**.

This is my audio tag in html file:

```
<audio controls loop preload id="musicGame">
  <source src="mp3/ambient.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="mp3/ambient.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

I'm calling my audio tag in javascript like that:

```
musicGame = $('#musicGame')[0];
```

Then I'm pausing it because I have a mute button and I need to pause all songs on my page in order for mute to work.

```
musicGame.pause();
```

This is where IE9 throws an error.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Change preload to preload="auto". Does it work then? Like most things, IE screws this all up.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find out what caused it?

Comment: Did you find out the issue?  I am also having the same problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`oog` is not supported in IE .. `mp3` however is supported in IE9+ ..

Try setting your `preload` attribute since IE9 might have issues with the `preload` attribute, so try and set it to `preload="metadata"`

```
<audio controls loop preload="metadata" id="musicGame">
   <source src="mp3/ambient.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
   <source src="mp3/ambient.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

- **metadata**: indicates that only audio metadata (e.g. length) is fetched; It also allows the browser to just download enough of the file to fetch metadata like size, dimensions, and duration.

Sometimes `preload="auto"` might work, but you will have to test!?

You might have to specify your audio source in the `audio` elements `src` attribute instead, without a child `source` element

```
<audio src="mp3/ambient.mp3" controls autoplay loop  id="musicGame"> 
    HTML5 audio not supported
</audio>
```

Also are using the right `DOCTYPE` for HTML5?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And are using the right `meta tag` for IE9 like this?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

And instead of using `$('#musicGame')[0]` have you also tried to just use?

```
document.getElementById("musicGame");
```

Some useful resource links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I am on a sickleave so I can'tcheck if this works now. The bounty will be over in 3 days. The answer is kind of vague though. If you see the question it is not about mp3 as this is included in the source. I have a feeling preload="metadata might be something, but will have to check when I get back on tuesday.

Comment: the mp3 is there as an example to try using the source attribute on the audio tag versus using the source element. To see if you see a difference when you have time to look and test

Answer (score 0):

Mp3 works, the problem that IE has is playing .wav and .ogg

Works in IE9 - Chrome - Safari and firefox

```
var sound = new Audio("/pop.mp3");
sound.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the DOCTYPE declaration `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the starting of your html code. It tells the browser how to render the page in standards compliant mode. Now `HTML5` audio will work in IE9.